# How to disable lock control panel in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, control-panel

I was enable the lock for Control Panel in Windows from Group Editor Policy. Now I want to disable the lock. Which option should I select: `Not Configured` or `Disabled` ?

Comment: You've answered your own question. "Now I want to disable the lock", and you've given `Disabled` as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go For any both will work,as by default it is set to Not Configured So i will prefer That